# Getting a object from inside an <object> tag in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have an HTML code with the following:

`<object class="sis" id="sis1" type="text/html" data="sis/sis1.html"></object>`

and in the imported file I have and `<h2>` I am trying to manipulate with JS, but I can figure out a way to select the element.

I've even tried:
`document.getElementById("sis1").getElementById("h2_id")`
but ->
`Uncaught TypeError: Object #<HTMLObjectElement> has no method 'getElementById'`

Comment: Simply use `document.getElementById("h2_id")`

Comment: I have..but seems like JS does not see the ids inside the <object> when trying that.
`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'attr' of null`

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried with?

```
document.getElementById('sis1').contentDocument.getElementById('h2_id');
```

Comment: I have now..but same result: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'attr' of null`